# Will upgrading my AWS EC2 t3.small instance to t3.medium give better CPU performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently using an EC2 t3.small instance (unlimited mode) for a service that is CPU bound and usually runs at 60-90% of max CPU utilization, but occasionally hits 100%. I want to upgrade to an instance with greater CPU performance so I don't hit max CPU utilization.

My question is: will upgrading to a larger t3 instance (e.g. t3.medium) give more CPU performance? From what I've been able to discern, the t3.medium still has 2 vCPUs just like t3.small. So will it give the same performance, just with more RAM and a higher baseline utilization/more CPU credits? In that case, the t3.xlarge with 4 vCPUs seems to be the next upgrade in the t3 family that gives more CPU capacity. But if that is the case, it seems like a c5.large would be the cheaper upgrade step.

Is my thinking correct here or am I missing something?

Comment: Your thinking appears to be correct. A c5.large would give you faster CPUs. A t5.xlarge would give you more CPUs (and more RAM).

Comment: @MarkB Yes, I know the c5.large would be faster. My question is: would a t3.medium be faster than a t3.small?

Comment: t3.medium would not be faster than a t3.small, it would just have more RAM and CPU credits.

Comment: Do you want only better performance or cost savings as well? You said you are using unlimited mode. How are you performing in regards to credit utilization from the extra? In the 60-90% range, you should be using much more than earning, so I'd assume you are paying for this. Your thinking is right from t3.small to t3.medium -- but if you go to t3.large, even tho it's still 2 CPUs, you get more credits/hour, which could lower your cost.

Comment: My main concern is a higher maximum CPU capacity. Within that requirement, I'd like to go for the cheapest solution. Indeed I'm currently always using more than the baseline performance, so consistently paying for additional CPU credits. And actually t3.medium offers the same amount of CPU credits as t3.small (24/hour), it just has double RAM (which I don't need). So for more CPU capacity, it seems like either t3.xlarge or c5.large is the way to go.

Comment: @Styco What type of workload are you running? Are you utilizing multiple CPUs, either via multithreading or by running multiple apps simultaneously? Is your usage being throttled (running too slow) on the current instance, and you want the apps to complete faster? Is it doing bursty-workloads (busy sometimes, not busy other times)? Have you considered using instances outside of the T-family to obtain consistent compute levels?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It's a single multi-threaded application running a set of calculations up to 20x per second, and performing REST queries. It usually runs at at least 60% CPU, but can spike to 100% occasionally. When it spikes to 100%, it's obviously CPU bound and I'd like to prevent that. I'm indeed now considering using a c5.large or c5a.large instance, since my only upgrade step in the T-family seems to be a t3.xlarge which is more expensive even when only using the baseline utilization.

Comment: I highly recommend that you experiment. It is easy to change instance types, so try a variety and see what best fits your workload. If it has a continuous workload, the T-family is probably not the best choice. The bottleneck will either be CPU, RAM or Disk, so keep trying to eliminate the bottleneck until you have acceptable performance. Also, consider using Spot Instances if it fits your workload. You can get more powerful instance types for less money, if the system can gracefully handle occasional instance outages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with different instance types, I came to the following conclusions:

1. Tried the c5a.large instance. It had very similar CPU performance to a t3.small instance. Still hitting the 100% utilization cap.
2. c5.large instance: Slightly better performance than c5a.large, but still hitting the CPU cap.
3. t3a.xlarge instance: with 4 vCPUs, I had much more CPU capacity and did not hit 100% CPU. I was using about 30 CPU credits per hour above the baseline, so I ended up with...
4. t3.xlarge: slightly better performance than t3a.xlarge and therefore using fewer CPU credits (about 15 per hour) which made this more cost effective than a t3a.xlarge.

So, in conclusion, a t3.medium was indeed not a suitable upgrade over a t3.small for increased CPU capacity. A c5.large was marginally better, but the real upgrade solution was going to a t3a.xlarge or t3.xlarge.